# octavia worker failed to establish a connection with amphora loadbalancer instance

Tags: openstack, amazon-elb

[Here](https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/contributor/guides/dev-quick-start.html#running-octavia-in-production) I find a sentence that I don't understand:

> Add appropriate routing to / from the ‘lb-mgmt-net’ such that egress is allowed, and the controller (to be created later) can talk to hosts on this network.

Can anyone explain the meaning of the above sentence in detail?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. The reason is that the firewall in the amphora load balancer mirror I made is not closed, which causes the port 9443 of the telnet load balancer instance to fail.